# IIS 7 Rewrite Module rules

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm setting up some rewrite paths using the IIS 7 rewrite module.

I just can't get my head around this one.

My friendly URL should look like this:
http://localhost/5f3ff4a5-1fb4-4470-904f-bd55e4fabc5d/marketing_performance/dashboard/

And rewrite to this:
http://localhost/marketing_performance/dashboard.aspx?account=5f3ff4a5-1fb4-4470-904f-bd55e4fabc5d

Comment: Sorry to say but http://localhost/5f3ff4a5-1fb4-4470-904f-bd55e4fabc5d/marketing_performance/dashboard/ doesn't look friendly at all to me...

Comment: I'm glad you're not the one seeing it on a daily basis then :-D

Comment: I actually nailed it:

Pattern: ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
Rewrite: {R:2}/{R:3}.aspx?account={R:1}

But when I have a page with a normal HTML link with href="../../test.aspx" it fails, with this error: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. So I guess i have to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Just add two conditions to this rule to check if the requested URL is not a file and is not a directory. That way your normal html links will continue to work:

<conditions>
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="isDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FINENAME}" matchType="isFile" negate="true" />
</conditions>

Answer (score 0):

I actually nailed it:
Pattern: ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
Rewrite: {R:2}/{R:3}.aspx?account={R:1}

But when I have a page with a normal HTML link with href="../../test.aspx" it fails, with this error: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. So I guess i have to refactor all my links such as this.